# Netbeans11 with JDK11 and javafx

Tags: javafx, netbeans, java-11

I'm new in Apache Netbeans 11 with JDK11, however i've been programming in jdk1.8 (netbeans 8.2) for a while but for school purposes i'm forced to use jdk11 this year, the problem is that I dont know, how to create new JavaFX FXML project. I've done some research and found out, that jfx is not a part of standard jdk anymore.

Then I found some tutorials how to run a javafx 11 project with adding the libraries, however it doesn't tell how to create a new project.

Is there any simple way how to add JavaFX 11 to my netbeans so the netbeans can use JavaFX 11 natively (I mean for example create new JavaFX 11 project with jdk11)

And if there isn't and I will have to use jdk 1.8, do I also need to install older Scene Builder or the SB11 will do the work (even for older javafx/jdk?

Comment: Start here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans

Comment: I've read this before, but if I understand well, this is a procces that I need to apply for all the new projects, so I cannot simply create new fxml app without doing this over and over again, right? It's possible that i'm wrong, I'm just really confused.

Comment: If you use Maven, there are two JavaFX archetypes that you can use to generate a default project, one with FXML. That is explained in the linked doc, Maven sections. Else, you can use the HelloFX [samples](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/NetBeans/Non-Modular/Java) as a start project.

Comment: Do note that there has been a bit of a name change: you will likely be looking for OpenJFX integration, not JavaFX. Netbeans 11.1 has some support for it, but it is very oriented around the usage of Maven. And that is not strange since OpenJFX itself pretty much encourages you to use Maven. So... learn to use Maven, it will be in your benefit for far more than only JavaFX stuff.

Comment: I've tried the Maven solution (I've never used Maven before), but as I'm following the docs, i'm still getting errors.. It's not what i'm looking for anyway. Gosh, why did they decide to seperate these things... I guess I will have to stick with older jdk. I can't imagine I have to set up/Maven the project everytime I create the new one

Comment: @JoséPereda Nometter what I do, how I follow or dont follow the docs, it eventuelly ends up with the same error msgs... Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --module-path 
Command execution failed.

Comment: Make sure you run NetBeans with Java 11+. That error shows you are running with Java 8. Docs mention how to edit the conf file for that.

Comment: @JoséPereda I've already edited the netbeans_jdkhome in netbeans.conf, also when I go to properties - build - compile, there is set Java Platform: JDK 11 (Default)

Comment: It is possible that you have an older Java in the path (environment variable), and that takes precedence. You can remove it or add first the Java 11 path. Also, if you are running Maven, you can use `<executable>path/to/java</executable>` in the plugin's configuration.

Comment: @Gimby OpenJFX doesn't encourage to use Maven. But now that we have the JavaFX artifacts in Maven Central, you can use Maven _or_ Gradle to use them, instead of having a local JavaFX SDK, that you can still have, of course. As you mentioned, using build tools is way more convenient. We'll agree that using _ant_ is discouraged.

Comment: There is a youtube video on what you are trying to do: [Setup JavaFX 11 or 12 on Netbeans 11 with JDK12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KMhgMCAjxo). It's surprisingly entertaining for such a dry topic, but there is some spicy language.

Comment: @skomisa I've seen that video and it's exactly what this topic is about. I was looking for some more user friedly solution then creating a new simple project, then set up the libraries in many settings. I was hoping for something like the old one (create specific FXML project with OpenJFX included). However there is a Maven way to that. I just had some nonsence errors, that I've have fixed right now.

Comment: Ok, SOLVED: I have had an errors telling me --module-path is an unrecognised option, altho I have had java_home set up on jdk11 and project on jdk11 as well. However, i needed to add system enviromental variable %JAVA_HOME% with jdk with higher priority then the old one. After that it still didnt run! BUT... Then I deleted the old system EV refferencing on jdk1.8. Since then the project runs with no errors. I tried to create EV refferencing the old jdk1.8 at the end of that Path list and it still run. (So there was a bug with prioritising the Paths I guess) Thank you all, espcly @JoséPereda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ok, **SOLVED**:

As you can read in https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans OpenJFK docs, there are basicly many options to create openJFX project (either with FXML)

- From IDE: That means that you have to add libraries, VM options, etc yourself for each project (As I mentioned in my question, not much user friendly solution I was looking for)
- Create Maven Project
- Create Gradle Project

**I chose the Maven**, yet I have had an errors telling me ***Unrecognized option: --module-path Command execution failed***., altho I have had java_home set up on jdk11 and project on jdk11 as well. However, i needed to add system enviromental variable %JAVA_HOME% with jdk with higher priority then the old one. After that it still didnt run! BUT... Then I deleted the old system EV refferencing on jdk1.8. Since then the project runs with no errors. I tried to create EV refferencing the old jdk1.8 at the end of that Path list and it still run. (So there was a bug with prioritising the Paths I guess) Thank you all, espcly @JoséPereda

**Sum – all steps I've done to solve** *Unrecognized option: --module-path Command execution failed.*

1. Set Apache NetBeans etc/netbeans.conf -> netbeans_jdkhome=/path/to/jdk-11
2. Create a new System Enviromental Variable called *JAVA_HOME* with value of path to new jdk (jdk11 in my case)
3. Edit System Enviromental Variable Path -> New -> *%JAVA_HOME%\bin* and move it above your old jdk path (yet my Maven project didn't run after this step)
4. Remove the old jdk path (jdk1.8 in my case)
5. Restart Apache NetBeans 11 -> Run Project -> It runs with no erros
6. I tried to add my old System Enviromental Varible Path (refferencing jdk1.8) and it still works.